# Java Sonar NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, sonarqube

I have error

> A "NullPointerException" could be thrown; "btn" is nullable here.

on code:

```
Button btn = getButton();
Assert.assertNotNull ("No button", btn);
btn.click();
```

How I can resolve this problem except case:

```
Button btn = getButton();
if (btn != null) {
  btn.click();
}
```

Comment: otherwise make sure getButton(); method always sends back a button.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `java-8`,then you can use `Optional`

```
Optional<Button> btn = getButton();//need to let return to Optional<Button>
btn.ifPresent(b -> b.click());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `Assert` should be used only in test classes. You can replace it with [java.util.Objects#requireNonNull](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)) (require Java 7):

```
Button btn = getButton();
Objects.requireNonNull(bnt).click();
```

or

```
Button btn = Objects.requireNonNull(getButton());
bnt.click();
```